# ng: ERROR: Can't resolve all parameters for component when trying to pass context into ComponentPortal

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

Trying to pass a context into ComponentPortal using Custom injection token and it works, however build --prod causes: 
**Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TooltipComponent**

If I put export of my InjectionToken into Service that generates my Portal, Errors leave, but I have circular dependency service -> component -> service

Service:

```js
import {
  ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, Injectable,
  InjectionToken, Injector
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  BasePortalOutlet, ComponentPortal, DomPortalOutlet,
  PortalInjector, PortalOutlet
} from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { TooltipComponent } from './tooltip.component';
import TooltipDataInjector from './TooltipInjector';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TooltipService {

  private _tooltipPortal: ComponentPortal;

  private _bodyPortalHost: DomPortalOutlet;

  constructor(
    private _factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private _injector: Injector,
  ) {
    this._tooltipPortal = new ComponentPortal(
      TooltipComponent,
      undefined,
      this.createInjector({})
    );

    this._bodyPortalHost = new DomPortalOutlet(
      document.body,
      this._factoryResolver,
      this._appRef,
      this._injector
    );
  }

  createInjector(data): PortalInjector {
    const tokens = new WeakMap([
      [TooltipDataInjector, data]
    ]);
    return new PortalInjector(this._injector, tokens);
  }

  show() {
    if (this._bodyPortalHost.hasAttached()) {
      this._bodyPortalHost.detach();
    }

    this._bodyPortalHost.attach(this._tooltipPortal);
  }

  hide() {
    this._bodyPortalHost.detach();
  }
}
```

Component:

```js
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import TooltipDataInjector from './TooltipInjector';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tooltip',
  templateUrl: './tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tooltip.component.scss']
})

export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(TooltipDataInjector) public data: any) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

TooltipInjector.ts:

```js
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const TooltipDataInjector = new InjectionToken<any>('TooltipDataInjector');

export default TooltipDataInjector;
```

How can I avoid these Error? JIT compiler builds normally

Comment: You don't import the component in the service, it's other way around

Comment: @DmitryKorolev you can not import component in component and not in service. this is not the right way. if you need data create function and pass data through function or create observer function on that observer pass data with one component get in other component